# What is "Device: 802h/2050d" stands for in inode?

Tags: files, filesystems, inode, stat

When I list an inode with `stat` command:

```
  File: 'text'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 8391119     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  cagdas)   Gid: ( 1000/  cagdas)
Access: 2017-07-31 17:00:00.513753567 +0300
Modify: 2017-07-31 17:00:00.513753567 +0300
Change: 2017-07-31 17:00:00.513753567 +0300
 Birth: -
```

what does **Device: 802h/2050d** stand for? When I do `stat` on char or block devices from `/dev`, it is shown as **Device: 6h/6d**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

802 (hexadecimal) is the combination of the major and minor numbers (8, 2) of `/dev/sda2` where the file `text` resides. The major number is placed in the most significant half of a 16-bit word, the minor number in the least significant half. For historical reasons the value is displayed like this, even though Linux since version 2.6 uses 32 bits for the device number (12 bits major, 20 bits minor). 2050 is the same value in decimal.